# $model->save() giving me an error

Tags: php, yii

i'm trying to make a comment system. when my form is posted, and calls my 'actionCreate' function. i get an error on firebug. But the data is stored in my DB. any idea what i'm doing wrong?

here is my action in my controller

```
    public function actionCreate()
    {

         /** @var Comment $comment */
         $comment = Yii::createComponent($this->module->commentModelClass);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
         $user=new User;

         $this->performAjaxValidation(array($comment, $user));
         //end of Ajax validation

        $_user = Yii::app()->request->getPost('User');

        if(isset($_POST[$cClass=get_class($comment)], $_user))
        {
            $comment->attributes = $_POST[$cClass];
            //$comment->type = $_POST[$cClass]['type'];
            //$comment->key  = $_POST[$cClass]['key'];

            $user->attributes = $_user;

            // determine current users id
            if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
                $comment->userId = null;
            } else {
                $comment->userId = Yii::app()->user->id;
            }

            if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) 
            {
                /* the error happens here */
                if($comment->save())
                {
                    // refresh model to replace CDbExpression for timestamp attribute
                    $comment->refresh();

                    // create new comment model for empty form
                    $comment = Yii::createComponent($this->module->commentModelClass);
                    //$comment->type = $_POST[$cClass]['type'];
                    //$comment->key  = $_POST[$cClass]['key'];
                }
                else { 
                     //Return messages from try/catch
                    echo CJSON::encode(array(
                        'msg' => 'Check your form, and fill up all required fields'
                    ));
                }

                Yii::app()->end();

            } 
            else 
            {
                if($comment->save()) {
                    $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('view','id'=>$comment->id));
                } 
                else {
                     //Return messages from try/catch
                    echo CJSON::encode(array(
                        'msg' => 'Check your form, and fill up all required fields'
                    ));
                }

                Yii::app()->end();
            }
        }

    }
```

my Comment Object

```
Comment Object
(
    [_type:Comment:private] => 
    [_key:Comment:private] => 
    [_new:Comment:private] => 
    [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
        (
            [money] => 2
            [reliability] => 2
            [recommend] => 1
            [pending] => 1
            [title] => test!!!!!
            [message] => test!!!!!test!!!!!test!!!!!test!!!!!test!!!!!test!!!!!test!!!!!
        )

    [_related:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [_c:CActiveRecord:private] => 
    [_pk:CActiveRecord:private] => 
    [_alias:CActiveRecord:private] => t
    [_errors:CModel:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [_validators:CModel:private] => CList Object
        (
            [_d:CList:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => CSafeValidator Object
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => message
                                )

                            [message] => 
                            [skipOnError] => 
                            [on] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [except] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [safe] => 1
                            [enableClientValidation] => 1
                            [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                            [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                        )

                    [1] => CInlineValidator Object
                        (
                            [method] => validateType
                            [params] => Array
                                (
                                    [on] => create
                                )

                            [clientValidate] => 
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => type
                                )

                            [message] => 
                            [skipOnError] => 
                            [on] => Array
                                (
                                    [create] => create
                                )

                            [except] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [safe] => 1
                            [enableClientValidation] => 1
                            [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                            [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                        )

                    [2] => CInlineValidator Object
                        (
                            [method] => validateKey
                            [params] => Array
                                (
                                    [on] => create
                                )

                            [clientValidate] => 
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => key
                                )

                            [message] => 
                            [skipOnError] => 
                            [on] => Array
                                (
                                    [create] => create
                                )

                            [except] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [safe] => 1
                            [enableClientValidation] => 1
                            [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                            [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                        )

                    [3] => CInlineValidator Object
                        (
                            [method] => validateType
                            [params] => Array
                                (
                                    [on] => create
                                )

                            [clientValidate] => 
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => type
                                )

                            [message] => 
                            [skipOnError] => 
                            [on] => Array
                                (
                                    [create] => create
                                )

                            [except] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [safe] => 1
                            [enableClientValidation] => 1
                            [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                            [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                        )

                    [4] => CInlineValidator Object
                        (
                            [method] => validateKey
                            [params] => Array
                                (
                                    [on] => create
                                )

                            [clientValidate] => 
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => key
                                )

                            [message] => 
                            [skipOnError] => 
                            [on] => Array
                                (
                                    [create] => create
                                )

                            [except] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [safe] => 1
                            [enableClientValidation] => 1
                            [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                            [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                        )

                    [5] => CRequiredValidator Object
                        (
                            [requiredValue] => 
                            [strict] => 
                            [trim] => 1
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => recommend
                                )

                            [message] => 
                            [skipOnError] => 
                            [on] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [except] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [safe] => 1
                            [enableClientValidation] => 1
                            [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                            [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                        )

                    [6] => CRequiredValidator Object
                        (
                            [requiredValue] => 
                            [strict] => 
                            [trim] => 1

                            [message] => 
                            [skipOnError] => 
                            [on] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [except] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [safe] => 1
                            [enableClientValidation] => 1
                            [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                            [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                        )

                    [7] => CRequiredValidator Object
                        (
                            [requiredValue] => 
                            [strict] => 
                            [trim] => 1


                            [message] => 
                            [skipOnError] => 
                            [on] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [except] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [safe] => 1
                            [enableClientValidation] => 1
                            [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                            [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                        )

                    [8] => CRequiredValidator Object
                        (
                            [requiredValue] => 
                            [strict] => 
                            [trim] => 1


                            [message] => 
                            [skipOnError] => 
                            [on] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [except] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [safe] => 1
                            [enableClientValidation] => 1
                            [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                            [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                        )

                    [9] => CUniqueValidator Object
                        (
                            [caseSensitive] => 1
                            [allowEmpty] => 1
                            [className] => 
                            [attributeName] => 
                            [criteria] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [message] => 
                            [skipOnError] => 1

                            [on] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [except] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [safe] => 1
                            [enableClientValidation] => 1
                            [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                            [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                        )

                    [10] => ENumberPlateValidator Object
                        (

                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => no_plate
                                )

                            [message] => 
                            [skipOnError] => 
                            [on] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [except] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [safe] => 1
                            [enableClientValidation] => 1
                            [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                            [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                        )

                    [11] => CSafeValidator Object
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => id
                                    [1] => message
                                    [2] => userId
                                )

                            [message] => 
                            [skipOnError] => 
                            [on] => Array
                                (
                                    [search] => search
                                )

                            [except] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [safe] => 1
                            [enableClientValidation] => 1
                            [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                            [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                        )

                )

            [_c:CList:private] => 12
            [_r:CList:private] => 
            [_e:CComponent:private] => 
            [_m:CComponent:private] => 
        )

    [_scenario:CModel:private] => insert
    [_e:CComponent:private] => Array
        (
            [onbeforesave] => CList Object
                (
                    [_d:CList:private] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => CTimestampBehavior Object
                                        (
                                            [createAttribute] => createDate
                                            [updateAttribute] => 
                                            [setUpdateOnCreate] => 
                                            [timestampExpression] => 
                                            [_enabled:CBehavior:private] => 1
                                            [_owner:CBehavior:private] => Comment Object
 *RECURSION*
                                            [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                                            [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                                        )

                                    [1] => beforeSave
                                )

                        )

                    [_c:CList:private] => 1
                    [_r:CList:private] => 
                    [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                    [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                )

        )

    [_m:CComponent:private] => Array
        (
            [CTimestampBehavior] => CTimestampBehavior Object
                (
                    [createAttribute] => createDate
                    [updateAttribute] => 
                    [setUpdateOnCreate] => 
                    [timestampExpression] => 
                    [_enabled:CBehavior:private] => 1
                    [_owner:CBehavior:private] => Comment Object
 *RECURSION*
                    [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                    [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                )

        )

    [_new:CActiveRecord:private] => 1
)
```

The error i get

```
 <b>Fatal error</b>:  Class name must be a valid object or a string in <b>/Library/WebServer/Documents/dev/common/lib/yii/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php</b> on line <b>395</b><br />
```

here is the CActiveRecord.php

```
public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        if(isset(self::$_models[$className]))
            return self::$_models[$className];
        else
        {
            $model=self::$_models[$className]=new $className(null); //this is line 395
            $model->attachBehaviors($model->behaviors());
            return $model;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which is line line 395?

Comment: Are you sure `self::$_models[$className]=new $className(null);` returnes a valid object?

Comment: Thank you. You're using `self::$_models` - $_models doesn't seem to be referenced in any of the code you've included; are you sure it's in scope?

Comment: sorry, dont quite get it. $comment is an object, plus it does save to db ( on this line $comment->save())

Comment: Yes but apparently your `save()` function invokes somewhere the `model()` function in `CActiveRecord.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it would work for a comment in my case:

```
public function actionCreate(){

    $comment = new Comment;

    if($_POST[get_class($comment)]){
        // save data here 
        if ( $comment->save() ) {
            // comment saved !!
        } else {
            // comment not saved
        }
    }

    $this->render('new',array('comment'=>$comment));
}
```

In your case, the comment is a component and not a model.
If for checking if the form was submitted is not something i know.

example for Comment model:

```
class Comment extends CActiveRecord
{
    $id;

    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function rules(){
    }
}
```

Comment: remember that Comment is a model under the models folder , extends CActiveRecord ....

Comment: Also, the error means autoload cant find Comment model .

Comment: Thanks, was trying to edit an extension to make it work better to my specs. still new to Yii.